# How redistribute data blocks after its reserved has been changed

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I have Hadoop 2.7.1. and decided to free couple gigs on one data node.

I changed hdfs-site.xml (defined dfs.datanode.du.reserved) on that node and restarted datanode process.

Hadoop datanode summary page started to show that the node free space fallen to zero but I still don't notice any data relocation.

What can I do to relocated datablocks to another nodes which are off limit now.

Answer (score 1):

I found the command which suits me:

```
$ hadoop/bin/hdfs balancer
```